# Convert string timestamp in format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ to SQL Server datetime without changing time zone

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc

I would like to transform a UTC timestamp with 5-6 ms digits into a SQL Server datetime. I do not want to localize or anything, just want to keep UTC but turn it into a datetime

e.g.

```
declare @utc_timestamp varchar(20) = '2022-10-05T13:12:02.000402Z';

-- Desired datetime format (is this even possible or does this not conform to SQL Server's datetime format?
2022-10-05 13:12:02.000402
```

Interestingly, this works:

```
declare @utc_timestamp varchar(20) = '2022-10-05T13:12:22Z';
select cast(@utc_timestamp as datetime)

-- result
2022-10-05 13:12:22.000
```

So it leads me to believe that SQL Server's datetime can only parse a UTC timestamp if it doesn't have too many ms digits.

Comment: I think `cast('2022-10-05T13:12:02.000402Z' as datetime2)` could help you. `datetime2` has a larger precision.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you @Vvdl. Feel free to post as an answer so I can give you credit. Simple and helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime2` for this, it has a higher precision.

`select cast('2022-10-05T13:12:02.000402Z' as datetime2)`

Answer (score 3):

@Vvdl already wrote an answer explaining how to solve this. I want to supplement that by providing references to the relevant parts of the documentation.

Allowed formats for `datetime` are documented here: [Supported string literal formats for datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime). The section on **ISO 8601** lists the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
```

`datetime2`, on the other hand, supports more decimal places: [Supported string literal formats for datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime2)

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]
```

In the examples, the documentation further explains that *"...[t]he time zone is truncated..."*, which explains why the trailing `Z` is allowed, even though it does not match the format described above.